# How can I add an image to my Mailer in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am working on a Rails 4 app and I need to reference an image from my public folder. I have the image saved in the public folder and I want to reference it from my mailer so it appears in the email that gets sent to the user. I am having some trouble getting it to render. When the email is sent, the image portion is just blank...

Here is the code:

**Mailer Class:**

```
 def set_default_layout_params()
    @layout = {
      subject: "Example",
      header_image: "/public/imageone.png",
    }
  end
```

I have store the image in the public folder of the app...